# How to get self name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say i want to create connected system of toggling a textbox by radio button. So each radio manage visibility of textbox.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Type" Content="First" Name="First" IsChecked="False" />
<TextBox Name="First" Visibility="FirstBox"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Type" Content="Second" Name="Second" IsChecked="False" />
<TextBox Name="Second" Visibility="Secondbox"/>
```

Okay, as you can expect if you check First radio button FirstBox should be visible but after checking Second radio, FirstBox is gone and SecondBox is now visible.
But i don't how to implement it simply. Is possible to use only xaml without code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You have to use a Binding in the Visibility property of the TextBox pointing to the IsChecked property of the CheckBox. You also need a Converter in this Binding which converts the bool to a Visbility.
But you should defenetly look for some tutorials first to get an idea how wpf works.